# Retrieving Values from List<Objects> of different dataTypes

Tags: c#

I'm storing different customobject in a List of Objects(List<(Objects)>). Below is my structure of the List.My customobjects doesn't inherit from the same class

```
[
      {
    "id": "1",
    "uniqueid": "secret",
    "emailaddress": "123@gmail.com", 
    "stateCode": "Xyz",
    },
    {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "secret",
    "Age": "123@gmail.com",     
    },
]
```

I want to check whether an object is present in the list based on the id field.I want to try reflection but couldn't find any helpful article that is performing reflection on System.Object

Comment: "_I'm storing different customobject in a List of Objects(List<(Objects)>)_" Collecting objects of rather dissimilar separate types (not sharing a common base type/interface) in the same collection is usually a sign of rather bad program design. If that is indeed the case here, rethink your approach of how you handle data inside your program. However, if the objects in the list are all of the same type or share a common base type, make it a list of that common type. That common type should be the type declaring the id property/field (or itself inheriting this property/field from a base type).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: “My customobjects doesn't inherit from the same class”; there's your problem, fix that.

Comment: Could you use a dictionary of objects rather than a list using the ID as the key. Dictionary<string ID,object Object>

Comment: you need to use a discriminator field that should be unique to the object you are looking for, later use reflection as @mxmissile recommended to ask for that customUniqueProperty to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ideal, but if you have to store unrelated types in the same list, you can cast to `dynamic`:

```
var results = list.Cast<dynamic>().Where( o => o.Id == 1 );
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1B6Zxq)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I agree with the comments.

This is not the best design / best usage of JSON structure.

In a JSON array, you should have only objects of similar type.  That way, you will never come into this situation.

**Solution to your problem:**

**Option 1:**

In that json array, you can get list of JObjects using newtonsoft API.

From the JObject you can read ID property using below syntax, assuming categories is the JArray you want to search into:

```
var list = categories.Select(c => (string)c["id"] == 1).ToList();
```

**Option 2:**

You can deserialize whole collection in a simple object which has only ID property.

e.g.

```
public interface IDummyInterface
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class SomeDummyClass : IDummyInterface
```

Using this dummy class you can call Deserialize method to get all the objects and then process them.  But remember you will not be able to use other properties in option 2 approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension method [ripped from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp):

```
public static object GetPropValue(this object src, string propName)
{
     return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

usage:

```
foreach(var o in Objects)
{
    if(o.GetPropValue("id") == someId)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You might have to do some converting/unboxing to get equatable values depending on the property's underlying data type. As others have pointed out, this is "magic" and "fuzzy". You are better off using an abstract class or an interface for your objects. Also this comes with all the fun Reflection caveats.